# Positioning draggable images with Javascript position()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with a draggable image inside a div, the script code looks like this:

```
var offset = 0,
        xPos = 0,
        yPos = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").draggable({
        containment: '#house_wall1',

        drag: function(){
            offset = $(this).position();
            xPos = offset.left;
            yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        },

        // Find original position of dragged image.
        start: function(event, ui) {
            // Show start dragged position of image.
            var Startpos = $(this).position();
            $("div#start").text("START: \nLeft: "+ Startpos.left + "\nTop: " + Startpos.top);
        },

        // Find position where image is dropped.
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            // Show dropped position.
            var Stoppos = $(this).position();
            $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that the x and y values are specified from the edge of the screen and not the div that they are supposed to. So if you have a screen with a lower resolution or if you make the browser window smaller then the x and y values will differ from a screen with a lower resolution.

I posted a problem similiar to this earlier and thought it was fixed, but unfortunatly it wasn't. I heard that using `position()` instead of `offset()` should do the job, but this still fix nothing. Maybe it's because the `position()` is equal to `offset()` in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a div as coordinates origin for left and top. you have to set the position style property. div position="relative" or div position absolute

Comment: appending: if you want to keep the div in the current position and serve as coordinates, you should use "relative" (and "absolute" for inner elements). positioning as absolute will put the div in (0, 0) WRT the ancestor DOM element which has another nonstatic position (which could be, in the worst case, the topleft corner of the document), or (left, top) WRT that element, if either prop is defined.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i forgot to mention that also the offset Properties are relative to the next parent which has positon: relative or absolute, if no parent has set the position property, the origin for IE is the client origin, what mozilla does is suspect for me, i hope they changed that soon to IE standard. you can see the difference by putting a border to the document.body and setting a div element to the document body and call alert (divid.offsetLeft); IE and mozilla will throw different values. Mozilla shows a value which only includes the body margin but not the border, and if you do a document.body.offset in mozilla it show a minus value????..... which is 0 in IE

exception are table inner Elements like td and tr , for them the table is the offsetParent